# Independent Eyes and Mouth animations in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to independently animate mouth, eyes and facial expressions on a 3D humanoid character in Unity. The problem I am having is the animation system always blends the eyes and mouth, making the character look like a slack-jawed yokel.

I have bones for neck, head, jaw, and 1 for each eye.

What I have tried.

Attempt 1

Create 3 layers. 1 for a body, 1 for a mouth, 1 for eyes. Add a head mask to the mouth and eye layers. Set the weight to 1, Blending to override for all layers.

What happens is the blend weight just gets set to 0.5 for both head layers.

Attempt 2

Use 1 body layer and 1 head layer with a head mask. In the head layer, use a Blend tree with a Direct Blend type. Have nested blend types for eye movement and jaw movement.

What happens is the blend weight just gets divided up between them. Mouth hangs open.

Attempt 3.

Use a transformed mask on the model animations. Restrict the Eye movement to just the transforms for the eye. Mouth animations to the jaw. Under mask restrict using Humanoid head and then Transform body or eyes, depending on the animation.

The Transform I need to mask it to a greyed out (because it's a humanoid model). Restricting it to a mesh makes the whole mesh move based on jaw movement or other weird things.

The question is how do you make parts of the face move independently from other parts. I want my character to be able to talk and look separately from each other, like in the real world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using only the jaw bone in the animator and using scripts to control the eyes and blend shapes (blinking).

For anyone trying to do the same thing.

I have seen YouTube video where they control multiple blend shapes using a blend tree with blend type of direct, but could not get that working. I suspect they did not have any bones in the face.

Another YouTube video of a red breasted robin animation who mixed shape keys and bone animations using the NLA Editor.